# Clojure: refresh running web app when html files change

Tags: clojure, leiningen, ring

I've set up my project with lein-ring to allow hot code reload. It does work when I change any .clj file while the app is running...

How can I make it the same for change in any html, css and js files. (located in resources/public...)

Here is my project.clj set-up:

```
(defproject ...
  :plugins [[lein-cljsbuild "1.0.4"]
            [lein-ring "0.9.2"]]      
  :ring {:handler votepourca.server/handler
          :auto-reload? true
          :auto-refresh? true}
  :resource-paths ["resources" "markup"]
  :source-paths ["src/clj"]
  ...)
```

**EDIT:**

I am using Enlive, and apparently, it needs an extra ring wrapper to allow static file reloading: `[com.akolov.enlive-reload "0.1.0"]`

So in my server.clj/core.clj/handler.clj, I now have this and it works perfectly!

```
(:require 
    [ring.middleware.reload   :refer [wrap-reload]]
    [com.akolov.enlive-reload :refer [wrap-enlive-reload]])
...

(defn app [routes]
  (-> routes 
      (wrap-params) 
      (wrap-reload)
      (wrap-enlive-reload))))
```

Thank you to "Kolov" the author of this lib https://github.com/kolov/enlive-reload

Answer (score 4):

Add :reload-paths in addition to :auto-reload?/:auto-refresh?. https://github.com/weavejester/lein-ring/blob/master/src/leiningen/ring/server.clj#L25

Comment: Thanks! This might help another person. In my case, the problem was that enlive keep the html file as they were on server start.  I've just updated question and shared my answer. I use an extra ring wrapper called `wrap-enlive-reload`